# Trouble with parsing JSON msg

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, quandl

I am calling a QUANDL API for data and getting a JSON msg back, which i am having trouble parsing, before sending to a database.  My parsing code is clearly not reading the JSON correctly.

Via the below code, i am getting the following (truncated for simplicity) JSON:
{"datatable":{"data":[["AAPL","MRY","2018-09-29",265595000000],["AAPL","MRY","2017-09-30",229234000000],["AAPL","MRY","2016-09-24",215639000000],["AAPL","MRY","2015-09-26",233715000000],["AAPL","MRY","2014-09-27",182795000000],["AAPL","MRY","2013-09-28",170910000000],["AAPL","MRT","2018-09-29",265595000000],["AAPL","MRT","2018-06-30",255274000000],["AAPL","MRT","2018-03-31",247417000000],["AAPL","MRT","2017-12-30",239176000000],["AAPL","MRT","2017-09-30",229234000000],["AAPL","MRT","2017-07-01",223507000000],["AAPL","MRT","2017-04-01",220457000000],["AAPL","MRT","2016-12-31",218118000000],["AAPL","MRT","2016-09-24",215639000000],["AAPL","MRT","2016-06-25",220288000000],["AAPL","MRT","2016-03-26",227535000000],["AAPL","MRT","2015-12-26",234988000000],["AAPL","MRT","2015-09-26",233715000000],["AAPL","MRT","2015-06-27",224337000000],["AAPL","MRT","2015-03-28",212164000000],["AAPL","MRT","2014-12-27",199800000000],["AAPL","MRT","2014-09-27",182795000000],["AAPL","MRT","2014-06-28",178144000000],["AAPL","MRT","2014-03-29",176035000000],"columns":[{"name":"ticker","type":"String"},{"name":"dimension","type":"String"},{"name":"datekey","type":"Date"},{"name":"revenue","type":"Integer"}]},"meta":{"next_cursor_id":null}}

```
import quandl, requests
from flask import request
from cs50 import SQL
db = SQL("sqlite:///formula.db")

data = 
requests.get(f"https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datatables/SHARADAR/SF1.json?ticker=AAPL&qopts.columns=ticker,dimension,datekey,revenue&api_key=YOURAPIKEY")

responses = data.json()
print(responses)

for response in responses:
    ticker=str(response["ticker"])
    dimension=str(response["dimension"])
    datekey=str(response["datekey"])
    revenue=int(response["revenue"])
    db.execute("INSERT INTO new(ticker, dimension, datekey, revenue) VALUES(:ticker, :dimension, :keydate, :revenue)", ticker=ticker, dimension=dimension, datekey=datekey, revenue=revenue)
```

I'm getting the following error msg (which i have in the past, and successfully addressed it) so strongly believe i am not reading the json correctly:
    File "new2.py", line 12, in 
        ticker=str(response["ticker"])
    TypeError: string indices must be integers

I want to be able to loop through the json and be able to isolate specific data to then populate a database.

Answer (score 0):

for your response structure, you have a nested dict object:

```
datatable
   data
      list of lists of data
```

so, this will happen:

```
responses = data.json()
datatable = responses['datatable']  # will get you the information mapped to the 'datatables' key
datatable_data = datatable['data']  # will get you the list mapped to the 'data' key
```

Now, `datatable_data` is a list of lists, right?  and lists can only be accessed by index point, not by strings

so, lets say you want the first response.

```
first_response = datatable_data[0]
```

that will result in

```
first_response = ["AAPL","MRY","2018-09-29",265595000000]
```

which you can now access by index point:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(first_response):
    print(f'{idx}\t{val}')
```

which will print out

```
0   AAPL
1   MRY
2   2018-09-29
3   265595000000
```

so, with all this information, you need to alter your program to ensure you're accessing the `data` key in the response, and then iterate over the list of lists.

So, something like this:

```
data = responses['datatable']['data']
for record in data:
   ticker, dimension, datekey, revenue = record  # unpack list into named variables
   db.execute(...)
```

Comment: Brilliant Jason.  Thank you very much.  I'm even more impressed you're responding on a Sunday.  Thanks again